Android pattern deep links with query params
I want to support only this deep link in application
https://example.com/magic_links/UUID?client_id=android
and NOT these:
https://example.com/magic_links/UUID?client_id=android1
https://example.com/magic_links/UUID?client_id1=android
https://example.com/magic_links/UUID
I tried several solutions like:
android:sspPattern=".*?client_id=android"
or
android:pathPattern="/magic_links/.*client_id=android.*"
Base component in manifest inside intent filters is:
<data
   android:host="example.com"
   android:pathPrefix="/magic_links/"
   android:scheme="https" />

Any ideas if there is any workaround?
Just to mention that i do not want to open link and if it is not match then open browser again or something like that. I am searching if there is any solution in order to match with pattern these type of links.


and NOT these

Filtering on query parameters will be part of Android 15, which is presently in its first beta release. It will be several years before this is available for most Android devices in then-current use.

I see, but for now we can patch this issue somehow for example can we verify only that client_id exist in link inside a pattern?

@ParaskevasNtsounos: No, sorry. Prior to Android 15, query parameters are not part of the deeplink filtering process.
